# How to notify view from model to change a value in backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

I have a model such as:

```
var resultEntityModel = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
        defaults : {
            name : "",
            bgOccurence : "",
            fgOccurence : "",
            bgOccurenceCount : "",
            fgOccurenceCount : "",
        },
        initialize : function() {

            var bgOccurence = this.set("bgOccurence", bgOccurence);      
            var fgOccurence = this.set("fgOccurence", fgOccurence);
            if((Math.abs((bgOccurence-fgOccurence))) >= 10){        
                // send information to view that background should be red
            }else{
                // send information to view that background should be white
            }
        },
});
```

And a view:

```
var resultEntityView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        tagName : "tr",
        template : ResultEntityPanel,
        initialize: function () {
               this.model.on(...) // it should take information from model 
                                  //and change css values according to this information
        },

    });
```

How can i take information from model and send it to view in order to change some values at .css file? I know the method but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: `this.model.on('change', function() { console.log("hidyho"); });` - but as to changing the .css file it'll be a no go, you can however use jQuery to change the CSS of something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the view to listen to changes on the model.  See [Backbone listenTo](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo).

Untested code, but something like this should do it:

model:

```
    var resultEntityModel = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
        defaults : {
            name : "",
            bgOccurence : "",
            fgOccurence : "",
            bgOccurenceCount : "",
            fgOccurenceCount : "",
        },
        initialize : function() {
            this.set("bgOccurence", bgOccurence);      
            this.set("fgOccurence", fgOccurence);
        }
    });
```

view:

```
    var resultEntityView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        tagName : "tr",
        template : ResultEntityPanel,
        initialize: function () {
            this.listenTo(this.model, "change:bgOccurence", this.setBg);
            this.listenTo(this.model, "change:fgOccurence", this.setBg);
        },
        setBg: function(model, value) {
            var bgOccurence = model.get('bgOccurence'),
                fgOccurence = model.get('fgOccurence');
            if ((Math.abs((bgOccurence-fgOccurence))) >= 10) {
                $('body').css({'background-color':'red'})
            } else {
                $('body').css({'background-color':'white'})
            }
        }
    });
```